# Repeater in my user control is empty on postback

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, user-controls, viewstate, repeater

I've looked at a lot of similar questions here, but to no avail.

So here goes...

I'm creating a set of user controls that display a list of grid-like tables.  Anyway, the objective is to list the grids, mess with the each grids data (client-side) and press save.  The grids work great, but when I press save teh repeater in the VIEWER is always empty.  Any help appreciated!

**The Basic Layout Goes Like This**

1. PAGE
2. ...updatePANEL
3. ......usercontrolVIEWER
4. .........saveBUTTON
5. .........repeaterCONTROL
6. ............usercontrolGRID
7. ............usercontrolGRID
8. ............ETC!

**The PAGE Looks Like This**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="body" runat="server">
    <asp:UpdatePanel id="udPanel" UpdateMode="Always" runat="server">
            <Triggers>
            </Triggers>
            <ContentTemplate>
               <uc:CommitImporterView ID="civData" runat="server" />
            </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>

public partial class CommitsAndActualsImporter : BaseForm
{
    #region EVENTS

    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        setUpEventHandlers();

        if (!IsPostBack)
            initalize();
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void myListOfGroups_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //.. Code to bind the list goes here ...

        myListOfGroups.SelectedIndex = setSelectedIndex(collection);
    }
    protected void myListOfGroups_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myGroup = myListOfGroups.Find(selectedItem => selectedItem.Key == key);
        dataSource = buildViewDataSource(base.ProjectKey, base.AsOf, myGroup.FcrGroupKey, myGroup.ContractorKey, myGroup.WbsKey);

        civData.AsOf = base.AsOf;
        civData.ProjectKey = base.ProjectKey;
        civData.DataSource = dataSource;
        civData.DataBind();
    }

    #endregion

    #region METHODS

    private void initalize()
    {
        ContractorInviteItems dataSource = listGroups(ProjectKey, AsOf);
        myListOfGroups.DataSource = dataSource;
        myListOfGroups.DataBind();
    }
    private void setUpEvents()
    {
        myListOfGroups.DataBinding += new EventHandler(myListOfGroups_DataBinding);
        myListOfGroups.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(myListOfGroups_SelectedIndexChanged);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

**The VIEWER User Control Looks Like This**

```
<%@ Register Src="~/UserControls/CommitImporterGrid.ascx" TagName="CommitImporterGrid" TagPrefix="uc" %>

<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" />

<asp:HiddenField ID="hidAsOf" runat="server" Value="" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="hidProjectKey" runat="server" Value="0" />

<asp:Repeater ID="repCommitImporterView" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <uc:CommitImporterGrid runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

public partial class CommitImporterView : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    #region PROPERTIES & FIELDS

    private enum basisUsed
    {
        Dollars,
        Hours,
        IsInvalid
    }

    public Object DataSource { get; set; }

    public DateTime AsOf { get { return Convert.ToDateTime(hidAsOf.Value); } set { hidAsOf.Value = value.ToString(); } }
    public Int32 ProjectKey { get { return Convert.ToInt32(hidProjectKey.Value); } set { hidProjectKey.Value = value.ToString(); } }

    #endregion

    #region EVENTS

    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);
        setupEvents();
    }
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        this.DataBind();
    }
    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreRender(e);
    }

    public override void DataBind()
    {
        base.DataBind();
    }

    protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Int32 count = repCommitImporterView.Controls.Count;

        foreach (Control control in repCommitImporterView.Controls)
        {
            if (control is UserControls.CommitImporterGrid)
            {
                string stop = "";
            }

        }
    }

    protected void repCommitImporterView_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DataSource == null)
            return;

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            Decimal totalSummaryCbudDollars = 0;
            Decimal totalSummaryCbudHours = 0;

            if (summaryValuesExist(out totalSummaryCbudDollars, out totalSummaryCbudHours))
                alignSummarizedRecords(totalSummaryCbudDollars, totalSummaryCbudHours);

            repCommitImporterView.DataSource = DataSource;
        }
    }
    protected void repCommitImporterView_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        ContractorInviteCommitsAndActualsImport record = (ContractorInviteCommitsAndActualsImport)e.Item.DataItem;
        CommitImporterGrid grid = new CommitImporterGrid();
        grid = (UserControls.CommitImporterGrid)Page.LoadControl("~/UserControls/CommitImporterGrid.ascx") as UserControls.CommitImporterGrid;

        grid.AsOf = this.AsOf;
        grid.ProjectKey = this.ProjectKey;

        grid.DataSource = getDataSource(record);
        grid.DataBind();

        repCommitImporterView.Controls.Add(grid);
    }

    #endregion

    #region METHODS

    private void setupEvents()
    {
        btnSave.Click += new EventHandler(btnSave_Click);

        repCommitImporterView.DataBinding += new EventHandler(repCommitImporterView_DataBinding);
        repCommitImporterView.ItemDataBound += new RepeaterItemEventHandler(repCommitImporterView_ItemDataBound);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

**The GRID User Control Looks Like**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are only binding the Viewer control when the user changes a DropDownList, and it's not getting bound when the page/control loads, either on initial load or on postback.  if you don't bind the repeater on postback, it won't have any of the data items you are expecting.

I would extract the contents of `myListOfGroups_SelectedIndexChanged` into a private method, and call it from `myListOfGroups_SelectedIndexChanged` and then also call it from `Page_Load` regardless of the state of `IsPostBack` (make sure it's called AFTER you databind `myListOfGroups`).  when you call it from `Page_Load`, it will get the user's selection from the DropDownList and re-bind the Viewer control which binds the Repeater.

the key point here is that you always need to bind repeaters on every page load, regardless of the value of `IsPostBack`.  otherwise there will be nothing in the repeater.